# itemtap event not firing on all taps

Tags: javascript, event-handling, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I'm using Sencha Touch 2.1. I have **Ext.carousel.Carousel** container and bunch of **Ext.dataview.Dataview** as pages inside carousel.

[image]

On each dataview I have a lot of buttons (rendered using CSS - so they are not buttons controls but simple divs with fancy styles). I'm trying to catch `itemtap` event when user taps on the "button".

Everything works fine in browser on the desktop. On the iPad however touch sensitivity is different and often I will not get `itemtap` event when user not carefully and somewhat slowly taps on the button. Carousel would start moving slightly as in swipe event was detected and carousel needs to change pages.

I tried to replace `itemtap` and use `itemtouchstart` instead. Button responsiveness got significantly better, but I often see false positives when user legitimately swipes between pages.

I'm stuck. I want to have responsive buttons and also swipe across to change pages.

Anybody seen something similar? Or solve it somehow?

Comment: Have you tried increasing friction to reduce swipe senstivity? `http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.fx.easing.Momentum-cfg-friction`

Comment: I haven't. Do you have link or description how exactly to approach this?

Comment: I also haven't tried it, but read that Sencha guys used this technique in fastbook. http://www.sencha.com/blog/the-making-of-fastbook-an-html5-love-story/

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue check out this forum [post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?246254-Button-sensitivity-issue-on-iPad-iOS-6) in sencha forum. Tragically i have the same issue & at the moment it cannot be solved using sencha alone perhaps a solution is available in phonegap but i dont know.